# Solr data import not index 2 entities

Tags: solr, solrj, dataimporthandler

I indexed one table (obs), using data import handler and everty think was good.

But when I try to add another entity and index the table (forms), nothing is indexed, even the obs table.

My data-config.xml:

```
<document>
        <entity name="obs"
          query="SELECT  o.uuid as id,  obs_id,  person_id,  obs_datetime, obs_group_id, cn1.name as concept_name,   
          cn2.name as coded, value_boolean,  value_datetime, value_numeric, value_text
          FROM openmrs.obs o 
          inner join (SELECT * FROM openmrs.concept_name c WHERE c.locale = 'en' AND concept_name_type = 'FULLY_SPECIFIED') as cn1 on cn1.concept_id = o.concept_id 
          LEFT join (SELECT * FROM openmrs.concept_name c WHERE c.locale = 'en' AND concept_name_type = 'FULLY_SPECIFIED') as cn2 on cn2.concept_id = o.value_coded 
          WHERE person_id='${dataimporter.request.personId}' AND o.voided=0 AND cn1.voided=0"  

          deltaImportQuery="SELECT  o.uuid as id,  obs_id,   person_id,  obs_datetime, obs_group_id, cn1.name as concept_name,   
          cn2.name as coded, value_boolean,  value_datetime, value_numeric, value_text
          FROM openmrs.obs o 
          inner join (SELECT * FROM openmrs.concept_name c WHERE c.locale = 'en' AND concept_name_type = 'FULLY_SPECIFIED') as cn1  on cn1.concept_id = o.concept_id 
          LEFT join (SELECT * FROM openmrs.concept_name c WHERE c.locale = 'en' AND concept_name_type = 'FULLY_SPECIFIED') as cn2 on cn2.concept_id = o.value_coded 
          WHERE o.uuid='${dih.delta.id}' AND o.voided=0 AND cn1.voided=0"

            deltaQuery="select o.uuid as id from openmrs.obs o 
            inner join concept_name cn on cn.concept_id = o.concept_id
            where person_id='${dataimporter.request.personId}'
            AND o.voided=0 AND cn.voided=0
            AND o.date_created &gt; '${dataimporter.request.lastIndexTime}'"
            deletedPkQuery="select o.uuid as id from openmrs.obs o 
            inner join concept_name cn on cn.concept_id = o.concept_id
            where person_id='${dataimporter.request.personId}'
            AND (o.voided=1 OR cn.voided=1) AND o.date_voided &gt; '${dataimporter.request.lastIndexTime}'"
            >
        </entity> 
      <entity name="forms"
          query="SELECT f.uuid as form_uuid, form_id, f.name as form_name, date_created, et.name as encounter_type_name
            FROM openmrs.form f 
            INNER JOIN openmrs.encounter_type et ON et.encounter_type_id = f.encounter_type 
            WHERE f.retired = 0" 

          deltaImportQuery="SELECT f.uuid as form_uuid, form_id, f.name as form_name, date_created, et.name as encounter_type_name
            FROM openmrs.form f 
            INNER JOIN openmrs.encounter_type et ON et.encounter_type_id = f.encounter_type
            WHERE f.uuid='${dih.delta.id}' AND f.retired = 0"

            deltaQuery="select f.uuid as form_uuid from openmrs.form f
            INNER JOIN openmrs.encounter_type et ON et.encounter_type_id = f.encounter_type
            where f.retired = 0
            AND f.date_created &gt; '${dataimporter.request.lastIndexTime}'"
            deletedPkQuery="select f.uuid as form_uuid from openmrs.form f
            INNER JOIN openmrs.encounter_type et ON et.encounter_type_id = f.encounter_type
            where f.retired = 0
            AND f.date_voided &gt; '${dataimporter.request.lastIndexTime}'"
            >
        </entity> 
</document>
```

schema.xml:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"
        required="true" />
    <field name="meta" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="false"
        required="false" /> 
    <field name="obs_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"
        required="false" />
    <field name="person_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"
        required="false" />
    <field name="concept_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" 
        required="false" />
    <field name="obs_datetime" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"
        required="false" />
    <field name="value_boolean" type="text_general" indexed="true"
        stored="false" required="false" />
    <field name="value_datetime" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"
        required="false" />
    <field name="obs_group_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"
        required="false" />
    <field name="value_numeric" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"
        required="false" />
    <field name="coded" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"
        required="false" />
    <field name="value_text" type="text_general" indexed="true"
        stored="false" required="false" />

     <field name="form_uuid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"
        required="false" />
    <field name="form_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"
        required="false" />
    <field name="form_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"
        required="false" />
    <field name="encounter_type_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"
        required="false" /> 
    <field name="date_created" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"
        required="false" />
```

Someone knows what the problem is? the queries are good.

I'm working with solrj version 4.3.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Anything suspicious in the logs?

Comment: Yeah. Actually this info tells nothing about your problems. We could'nt check this quieries. Probably this is because you don't select anything as id field from second table.

Comment: Do you have a unique ID for each entry that you are indexing? If not, the indexing process might silently ignore the new documents.

As a rule of thumb, always have a unique ID for each indexed document.

Comment: How can I tell Solr what is the unique id for each table?
In schema.xml I have this line: <uniqueKey> id </uniqueKey>. As I know, only one field is allowed to be marked as uniqueKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like "obs" is working because you are using unique key:

```
o.uuid as id
```

You need something like that for the forms as well. Possibly:

```
f.something as id
```

Without id key your documents are ignored as @Zouzias mentioned